# Maven2 Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, pdfbox

I have just added dependencies to a project so that my jar, specifically pdfbox 1.6, can see other jars. After adding my dependencies with the right click onto project feature that maven offers how can I be sure that the dependencies work, and that what I've done is correct? I view a pom.xml file that has been created so what are the target folder and classes,test-classes subfolders used for? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse Maven Dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997471/eclipse-maven-dependency)

Comment: Try to download indexes update like in this eclipse maven tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html

Answer (score 1):

you can build your project and see if the dependencies are in the final artifact. Also eclipse can show you the dependencies under maven dependencies, see the screenshot : [image]